# Does Microsoft plan introduce new features (like modern web standards support) in IE11 after Microsoft Edge will release on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, web-standards

As far as I know IE Edge will be only on Windows 10. So for example there would no Web Audio or WebRTC support on IE11 in Windows 7. In general is this means that people who uses IE on Windows that is older that windows 10 will not have access to modern technologies like WebRTC or others that IE11 don't support now?

Comment: We're not Microsoft, this will be mostly speculation.

Comment: Microsoft has pretty clearly indicated their intentions for each browser.  See http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/17/building-a-more-interoperable-web-with-microsoft-edge/ and other posts in the new blog from the dev team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good resource to review to answer the specifics of your question is http://dev.modern.ie/

This shows the features roadmap for both browsers: what's working now, what's in development, what's planned for Edge only, and what's working in other major browsers. A full map is here: http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/ You can filter by specific feature.

Comment: As I see there is plenty of staff that is Edge only. Even "On Development"  shows "In Development by Microsoft Edge". Is it means that it would not be  implemented in IE11?

Comment: can't 100% say for sure, but most likely, if a feature says 'in Edge' then it's likely to be an Edge-only feature going forward.

Comment: Microsoft is on record as saying that Edge is the browser of the future.  IE will focus on providing compatibility for legacy applications; however, Edge will receive the lion's share of innovation.  To learn more, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2015/04/29/microsoft-edge-is-the-browser-for-windows-10.aspx, http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/06/17/building-a-more-interoperable-web-with-microsoft-edge/, and other posts in each blog.